# How can I access a field of a double structure?

Tags: structure, common-lisp

I have a structure year which contains groups of students. Student is another stucture

```
(DEFSTRUCT student
   (fname "nil" :type string)
   (lname "nil" :type string)
   (initGroup 0 :type integer)
   (options nil)
   (marks nil)
   (newGroup nil)
)
```

Mark is a structure

```
(DEFSTRUCT mark
   (avgy1 0.0 :type single-float)
   (avgy22 0.0 :type single-float)
   (avgy33 0.0 :type single-float)
   (finalAvg 0.0 :type single-float) 
)
```

and I want to access the finalAvg field of this structure through my year structure because I want to sort all the students in my year descending.

I have tried many combinations but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**"  Can you show some of those "many combinations" that you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
(setf (year-students *year-2013*)
      (sort (year-students *year-2013*)
            '>
            :key (lambda (student)
                   (loop for mark in (student-marks student)
                         maximize (mark-finalavg mark)))))
```

Style remarks:

- avoid dangling parentheses on their own lines
- Avoid CamelCase like `finalAvg`. Use `final-avg` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

[Rainer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420303/1281433) has this nailed but I just would add the following:  the core thing to note is that you can use accessors on the results from other accessors. For example if the variable `jim` held a student then the following will get you his first avg-mark (assuming that `marks` is a list of `mark` structs):

```
(final-avg (first (marks jim)))
```

It might be written like this in a language like Python:

```
jim.marks[0].final-avg
```